# Closest distance between a point from the boundary of the unit ball and a point from the inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be an inner product space over $K$ and let $x_0$∈ X. Find $x ∈ ∂B(0, 1)$ that is closest to $x_0$.

How to start this, I don't have any idea.

Comment: Have you tried getting a feel for the problem by looking at a finite-dimensional (say $2$ dimensional) picture?

Comment: Yes, in 2-dimensional it is not a problem, as we can do by geometry. The distance of point from the centre minus 1.